# Product of two sequential spaces is not sequential

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space

The product of two sequential topological spaces is not necessarily sequential. Could you give an example confirming this?

As each first-countable space is sequential and the operation of taking a product of finite (and even countable) number of spaces preserves first-countability, at least one of the two factors should not be first-countable.

Comment: I believe [this paper](https://qspace.qu.edu.qa/bitstream/handle/10576/9892/07-85-5-0004-fulltext.pdf?sequence=10&isAllowed=y) gives an answer (see section 2 of interesting spaces)

Comment: The example in 2 gives a sequential compact space whose square is not sequential.